# How can I loop through two arrays at once?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to arrange two arrays together and the results keep coming out incorrect. I'll show you my code, the results I'm getting and the results I'm looking for.

I guess I'm just doing it wrong but not sure how else to do it.

My code:

```
$data1 = [
    'a: 1',
    'a: 2',
    'a: 3',
    'a: 4',
    'a: 5'
];

$data2 = [
    'b: 1',
    'b: 2',
    'b: 3',
    'b: 4',
    'b: 5'
];


foreach($data1 as $item1)
{
    foreach($data2 as $item2)
    {
        echo $item1 . '<br/>';
        echo $item2 . '<br/>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';
    }
}
```

The Results: (shortened to save space)

```
a: 1
b: 1

a: 1
b: 2

a: 1
b: 3

a: 1
b: 4

a: 1
b: 5
```

The results I'm looking for is the following:

```
a: 1
b: 1

a: 2
b: 2

a: 3
b: 3

a: 4
b: 4

a: 5
b: 5
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Problem

Well the problem is of course your nested foreach loop. Because for each element of your `$data1` array you loop through the entire `$data2` array (So in total there are `$data1` * `$data2` iterations).

### Solutions

To solve this you have to loop through both arrays at once.

#### [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) method <sub>(PHP >=5.3)</sub>

You can do this with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and pass all arrays to it which you want to loop through at the same time.

```
array_map(function($v1, $v2){
    echo $v1 . "<br>";
    echo $v2 . "<br><br>";
}, $data1, $data2 /* , Add more arrays if needed manually */);
```

<sub>**Note:** If the amount of elements are uneven you won't gen any errors, it will just print `NULL` (Means you won't see anything)</sub>

#### [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) method <sub>(PHP >=5.3)</sub>

Use a [`MultipleIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php) and [attach](http://php.net/manual/en/multipleiterator.attachiterator.php) as many [`ArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php) as you need.

```
$it = new MultipleIterator();
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($data1));
$it->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($data2));
//Add more arrays if needed 

foreach($it as $a) {
    echo $a[0] . "<br>";
    echo $a[1] . "<br><br>";
}
```

<sub>**Note:** If the amount of elements are uneven it will just print all values where both arrays still have values</sub>

#### [`for loop`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) method <sub>(PHP >=4.3)</sub>

Use a for loop with a counter variable, which you can use as key for both arrays.

```
$keysOne = array_keys($data1);
$keysTwo = array_keys($data2);

$min = min(count($data1), count($data2));

for($i = 0; $i < $min; $i++) {
    echo $data1[$keysOne[$i]] . "<br>";
    echo $data2[$keysTwo[$i]] . "<br><br>";
}
```

<sub>**Note:** Using [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) is just so that this also works if the arrays don't have the same keys or are associative. [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) is used to only loop through as many elements as every array has</sub>

#### [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) method <sub>(PHP >=5.0)</sub>

Or if the arrays only have unique values, you can [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) both arrays, so that `$data1` can be accessed as key and `$data2` as value.

```
foreach(array_combine($data1, $data2) as $d1 => $d2) {
    echo $d1 . "<br>";
    echo $d2 . "<br><br>";
}
```

<sub>**Note:** The arrays must have the same amount of elements, otherwise `array_combine()` will throw an error</sub>

#### [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) method <sub>(PHP >=5.6)</sub>

If you want to print more than 2 arrays at the same time or just an unknown amount of arrays, you can combine the `array_map()` method with a [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) call.

```
$func = function(...$numbers){
    foreach($numbers as $v)
        echo $v . "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
};
call_user_func_array("array_map", [$func, $data1, $data2]);
```

<sub>**Note:** Since this kinda uses the `array_map()` method, it behaves the same with uneven amount of elements. Also since this method only works for PHP >=5.6 you can just remove the arguments and change out `$numbers` with [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) in the foreach loop and then it also works for PHP >=5.3</sub>

Comment: i've having this weird issue, instead of echoing the values i'm using array_push($somevar, ['item1' => $item1, 'item2' => $item2]); but the $somevar unregisters as an array within the array_map() function. and i had set it as an array outside of the iteration function.

Comment: @SarmenB. Please post a little link to an online IDE or so with your current code.

Comment: its ok i got it to work with MultipleIterator. But here is the code anyway http://pastie.org/private/ppeu5xre2khelnidsowpq

Comment: i meant array_push not array_merge (when you see the snippet)

Comment: @SarmenB. So first problem is, that the variable: `$collection` is out of scope in your anonymous function. To solve it you can use [`use()`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) and pass it by reference, so you won't lose the data in each call. And if you use `array_push()`, then everything else is correct, or do it like this: http://3v4l.org/6DEKO (just without array_push)

Comment: nice thanks! i'm starting to like the subject of arrays now, it was on subject i would avoid when i was a noob.

Comment: btw, do you know of an alternative to array_map when iterating objects? I'm looking through php.net to see if i see anything myself

Comment: @SarmenB. *objects* Depends what structure they have and what you want to display.

Comment: using the sample above as an object instead of an array

Comment: @SarmenB. Then it would get more complicated, especially when you have numbers as property names and when the object also would come from an array.

Answer (score 7):

use key from 1 to get row in 2

```
foreach($data1 as $k=> $item1)
{
        echo $item1 . '<br/>';
        echo $data2[$k] . '<br/>';
        echo '<br/><br/>';
}
```