# PHP display order for iterating through multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

In essence, I have 3 arrays. These are serialised, stored to the DB, un-serialised and then outputted to a page. `myFirstArray`, `mySecondArray`, & `myThirdArray`.

From what I gather - I need to be using a `foreach` loop, or a `for` loop with a counter, as the 3 arrays are all of (the same) unknown length. By that I mean one user may have stored 4 items into each of the 3 arrays, but another user might have stored 8 items into each of the 3 arrays.

I'm trying to get the output to look something like this:

myFirstArray[0], mySecondArray[0],  myThirdArray[0] 
 
myFirstArray[1], mySecondArray[1],  myThirdArray[1] 
myFirstArray[2], mySecondArray[2],  myThirdArray[2]

The current code I have is as follows:

```
foreach ($myFirstArray as $value1){
    echo $value1 . " ";
}
foreach ($mySecondArray as $value2){
    echo $value2 . " ";
}
foreach ($myThirdArray as $value3){
    echo $value3 . "<br>";
}
```

I am aware that this code is never going to output my arrays as I would like, but I'm having some difficulty with working out the logic behind what I need. I haven't rushed straight to StackOverflow to ask, but nothing else I've seen has been very helpful!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32061254/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both arrays have the same length, I propose

```
$length = count($myFirstArray);
for($i = 0; $i <$length ; $i++) {
    echo $myFirstArray[$i].','.$mySecondArray[$i].','.$myThirdArray[$i].'<br/>';
}
```

This will loop through all of your arrays at the same time :) .

Comment: I've tried this code, but it doesn't appear to output anything.

Comment: @SixTailedFox, sorry I missed the count function, just edited it. I'm too used to OO programming :)