# Can i write two foreach in only one?

Tags: php, mysql

In my code I have this:

```
$im  = $database->query("SELECT * FROM cms_messaggi_importanti WHERE messo_da = :id ORDER BY ID DESC", array("id"=>$functions->Utente("id")));
foreach($im as $imp){
    $mex_i  = $database->query("SELECT * FROM cms_messaggi WHERE id = :id ORDER BY ID DESC", array("id"=>$imp['id_mex']));
     foreach($mex_i as $mex_imp){ 
     }
}
```

Can I write this code in only one? Because I have to use a lot of variable with this method. Is there a solution to my problem? For example, using "JOIN"?

Comment: Yes the solution is to use join

Comment: @e4c5 you can give me an example? I'm not very practical..

Comment: There are many MySQL guides and tutorials out there that will teach you how to write a simple JOIN.  You should take the time to actually learn what you're doing instead of just copy/pasting what someone else gives you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061254/how-can-i-loop-through-two-arrays-at-once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (and should) do your query in one go, and then iterate over those results:

```
$im  = $database->query("
    SELECT    * 
    FROM      cms_messaggi_importanti mi
    LEFT JOIN cms_messaggi m ON m.id = mi.id_mex
    WHERE     messo_da = :id 
    ORDER BY  mi.ID DESC, 
              m.ID DESC", 
        array("id"=>$functions->Utente("id")));

foreach($im as $imp){
    //...
}
```

You will probably need to replace the `SELECT *` by a more precise column list, which will be the columns available in the result set.