# Insert two arrays data to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm getting two form datas as array .I want to insert those data in my table.

## arrays

```
> var_dump($name);
array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "allen" [1]=> string(4) "dave" [2]=> string(3) "len" }

> var_dump($designation) ;
array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "analyst" [1]=> string(8) "designer" [2]=> string(2) "pm" }
```

below is my table insert query

```
foreach ($name as $list) {
    $sig = new Names;
    $sig->name =$list;
    $sig->designation =?;
    $sig->festival = $id;
    $sig->save();
}
```

how to insert desgination array ? pls advice

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32061254

Comment: @Rizier123 : Thanks It helps :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two arrays in foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480803/two-arrays-in-foreach-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I loop through two arrays at once?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061254/how-can-i-loop-through-two-arrays-at-once)

Comment: @dil What is the status of this question?  It appears that Rizier123's comment was helpful to you, and you may have also upvoted Stephen's suggested duplicate link.  If you found your solution from a duplicate question, please delete your question and spare SO the unwanted bloat.  If your question is unresolved, please update your question with any new details or attempts that you have made.