# Consolidating multiple array_map functions into one

Tags: php, implode, array-map

I'm using Laravel and in my blade template I have several calls to `array_map()` in order to stringify an array with the `&` delimiter and for the sake of cleanliness I'm trying to consolidate these calls into one where the logic looks like this:

```
@foreach ($draws as $draw)
    @php
        $team = $draw->team;
        $participants = array_filter($team ? [$team->partner_one ?: false, $team->partner_two ?: false] : [$draw->user]);
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $draw->event->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->event_activity->activity_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->draw_order }}</td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', array_map(function($v, $k){
                return $v->meta('state_back_number');
            }, $participants, array_keys($participants)))}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', array_map(function($v, $k){
                return $v->last_name.', '.$v->first_name;
            }, $participants, array_keys($participants)))}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', array_map(function($v, $k){
                return $v->address(true)->get()[0]->city.', '.$v->address(true)->get()[0]->state;
            }, $participants, array_keys($participants)))}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', array_map(function($v, $k){
                return $v->meta('section');
            }, $participants, array_keys($participants)))}}
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>{{$draw->payout_final ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Something I had tried was on the line directly below the `$participants` declaration

```
$user_data = array_map(function($v, $k){
  return ['state_back_number' => $v->meta('state_back_number'), 'name' => $v->last_name.', '.$v->first_name, 'hometown' => $v->address(true)->get()[0]->city.', '.$v->address(true)->get()[0]->state];
}, $participants, array_keys($participants));
```

And ideally it would've resulted in me being able to call `implode()` with the respective array key like so `implode(' & ', $user_data['state_back_number']);` but instead the array I get is jumbled and and has unnecessary indexes.

My question is: how do I combine these `array_map()` calls to create a single array which I can call `implode` on to create the desired string and save 10 or so lines of code?

Comment: These computations are much better off in a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `array_map()` once and use it to populate four more arrays: `$state_back_numbers`, `$last_names`, `$addresses`, and `$sections`. (It would probably be smarter to use another method to [loop through two arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32061254/how-can-i-loop-through-two-arrays-at-once) but it was easiest to do it the way I did.)

After you've populated those four arrays, you can `implode()` them.

```
@foreach ($draws as $draw)
    @php
        $team = $draw->team;
        $participants = array_filter($team ? [$team->partner_one ?: false, $team->partner_two ?: false] : [$draw->user]);
        
        $state_back_numbers = [];
        $last_names = [];
        $addresses = [];
        $sections = [];

        array_map(function($v, $k) use (&$state_back_numbers, &$last_names, &$addresses, &$sections) {
              $state_back_numbers[] = $v->meta('state_back_number');
              $last_names[] = $v->last_name.', '.$v->first_name;
              $addresses[] = $v->address(true)->get()[0]->city.', '.$v->address(true)->get()[0]->state;
              $sections[] = $v->meta('section');
            }, $participants, array_keys($participants));
    @endphp
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $draw->event->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->event_activity->activity_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $draw->draw_order }}</td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', $state_back_numbers)}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', $last_names)}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', $addresses}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{implode(' & ', $sections}}
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>{{$draw->payout_final ? 'Yes' : 'No'}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```